# QLoggingCategory is missing in Qt

Tags: qt

Trying to build project on newly installed Qt that runs on Centos 64 bit. Got error:

```
/home/me/pro/LoggingCategories.h:4: error: QLoggingCategory.h: No such file or directory
 #include <QLoggingCategory.h>
                              ^
```

Why it is missing? I suppose it should be installed as default. How to fix error?

UPD

Got the same error after changing `#include <QLoggingCategory.h>` to `#include <QLoggingCategory>`

```
/home/me/pro/LoggingCategories.h:4: error: QLoggingCategory: No such file or directory
 #include <QLoggingCategory>
                            ^
```

Comment: Replace it with `#include <QLoggingCategory>`. Please read the documentation carefully.

Comment: Got the same error after changing `#include <QLoggingCategory.h>` to `#include <QLoggingCategory>`. More details in UPD

Comment: Which Qt version do you use? QLoggingCategory was introduced in Qt 5.2. Also, what include paths did you configure? maybe you need `#include <QtCore/QLoggingCategory>`

Comment: did you add `QT += core` to the *.pro file?